# Append Jquery plugin to document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a plugin called minicolors for jquery [link](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/02/jquery-minicolors-a-color-selector-for-input-controls/). I am trying to appened a color picker here (in 2 places, a div and table just for testing)  with a button click, it seems though that it only works on the second button click, the first simply returning an empty input box.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">


            function addPicker() {

            $(document).ready( function() {
                            $(".colorpick").miniColors({
                change: function(hex, rgb) {

                    }
                });
            });

                var picker = "<input type= 'text' class='colorpick' size='6' autocomplete='on' maxlength='10' value='' />";

                $("#datatable > tbody").append("<tr><td>"+picker+"</td></tr>");
                $("#testdiv").append(picker);
            }



            </script>
            <div id="testdiv"></div>
            <button onclick =" addPicker();">Button</button>
```

No Idea why this is not working.

Comment: remove document.ready from the function and try it that way.

Comment: please post this in jsFiddle :) as far as I see you already have a few weird things in your code.
(eg .. why call $(document).ready() in a function??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
  $(document).ready( function() {

       $('.addButton').click(function(){
           $("<input type= 'text' class='colorpick' size='6' autocomplete='on' maxlength='10' value='' />").appendTo("#datatable tbody").wrap('<tr><td></td></tr>');

           $('.colorpick').miniColors();
       });

  });​
```

Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hCVpX/12/

Comment: this is really close but the actual color box picker doesn't show. It still has most the functionality however

Comment: Can you try again please. You must add class "addButton" at your button.

Comment: yep did that, the picker box is showing now but its not getting added to the same cell as the input box, its just appended to the bottom table body without sitting in any table cell or row